# Drilldown broken in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, drilldown

I had read elsewhere in SE there was a recent drilldown fix but it doesn't seem to work for me (unless I'm doing some wrong that I can't see)...

```
  ...     
    series: [{
        name: 'Year 1800',
        drilldown: 'drill',
        data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            name: 'drilled',
            id: 'drill',
            type: 'pie',
            data: [
                ['fred', 200],
                ['wilma', 999]
            ]
        }]
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pdnfiddle/32s96nyz/3/

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the drilldown id on each point. Like:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Year 1800',
    data: [{
        y: 107,
        drilldown: 'drill'
    },
    31, 635, 203, 2]
}],
```

If you want to make it "global" that regardless of what point you click on you get the same drilldown series then you can roll your own on the point.events call.